# Casting dictionary of sets to JSON Object

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to build request body like this form:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1, 
        "id": 2,
        "id": 4
    }
}
```

My first idea was built json from string and cast it to dictionary String and Any, but this solution have a issue. Some "id" are missing on casting by JSONSerialization step.

I tried to use:

```
var dictionary: [String : Any] = ["name" : "John"]()
var selectedIDs = Set<NSDictionary>()

// Adding values to selectedIDs set
let userIDDict = ["id" : id] as NSDictionary
selectedIDs.insert(userIDDict)

dictionary.updateValue(selectedIDs, forKey: "user")
```

But it cannot be cast by JSONSerialization (Invalid type in JSON write).
How can i resolve problem, which i'm facing?

Comment: This isn't valid JSON, so normal JSON serializers are not going to generate it.

Comment: you can't have multiple same key names

Comment: @Adrian `Codable` will not generate this output.

Comment: (To be clearer, the JSON spec, RFC 8259, does permit duplicate keys. It just notes that it's unpredictable what will happen and it will not be interoperable between parsers. This is an unfortunately oblique way of saying that this is undefined behavior.)

Comment: You might as well have an array named "id", `"id": [1, 2, 4]`

Answer (score 1):

Creating this request is not a problem; it's just not proper JSON, so you shouldn't try to use `JSONSerialization`. It's just a string, and so you can create that string:

```
let idKeyValues = ids.map { "\"id\": \($0)" }.joined(separator: ",\n        ")

let request = """
{
    "user": {
        \(idKeyValues)
    }
}
"""
```

===>

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "id": 4
    }
}
```

The proper way to express this in JSON would be:

```
{
    "user": {
        "ids": [1, 2, 4]
    }
}
```

With that, a `Codable` implementation should be very straightforward.